# Apache won't start on MAMP in Yosemite/Virtual Hosts don't resolve to their directories

Tags: apache

I recently updated to Yosemite on my mac and I had been using virtual hosts on MAMP, and even after updating they were working fine, however I could not create a new virtual host. I messed around with a couple things, started and restarted apache and now all my virtual hosts resolve to a page that says "It Works!" and apache on MAMP won't start. I've already done the apache fix by changing the envarrs file to _envarrs. This is my apache error log file

`AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using

Harrys-MacBook-Pro.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Nov 10 21:10:53.256847 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26139] AH00163: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.6.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 10 21:10:53.256901 2014] [core:notice] [pid 26139] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Nov 10 21:12:14.386605 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26139] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Harrys-MacBook-Pro.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Nov 10 21:12:16.330823 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27444] AH00163: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.6.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 10 21:12:16.330885 2014] [core:notice] [pid 27444] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Nov 10 21:13:12.913471 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27444] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Harrys-MacBook-Pro.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Nov 10 21:16:44.629618 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 54] AH00163: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.6.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 10 21:16:44.629939 2014] [core:notice] [pid 54] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Nov 10 21:27:57.710912 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 54] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Harrys-MacBook-Pro.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Nov 10 21:28:04.948306 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3305] AH00163: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.6.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 10 21:28:04.948362 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3305] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'`

Comment: Yosemite comes with its native Apache Server. Have you disabled it before attempting to start MAMP Apache?

Comment: No I haven't, what command would I run to disable it?